# Updating AppWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I'm launching an activity on a buttonclick from AppWidget. The user enters some data on the activity and when user closes the activity, I want to update the data user entered in a TextView on AppWidget. Any idea how to do that? 
I have successfully launched activity from AppWidget, only problem being updating the AppWidget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`RemoteViews`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) and the [`AppWidgetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html):

```
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(
    context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textBoxId, "new textbox content");

manager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
```

Comment: In which method of my class extending AppWidgetProvider should I add this?

Comment: The snippet will update a `TextView` in your widget. You wrote that you want to update your widget when the user closes an `Activity` so that `Activity`'s `onPause` method would be a good place for example.

Comment: @AmitChintawar where does the appWidgetId come from ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the appwidget update method from the host application activity or fragment.

This is how I have done it:

```
    int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication()).
    getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), MyWidget.class));
    MyWidget myWidget = new MyWidget();
    myWidget.onUpdate(this, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this),ids);
```